# Can content builder data slots be limited to specific blocks by ID or name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, content-builder

Just wondering if content builder data slots can be limited to specific blocks, rather than just block types, using the data-allowed-blocks attribute?

was hoping for something like...

data-allowed-blocks="ContentBlockbyID("111111");"

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no provision as of now in SFMC to allow only certain blocks with block ID.

We can only limit it with either with block names or by number of blocks.

Below is the code sample for number of blocks allowed and what type of blocks to be used.

```
<div data-type="slot" data-key="7vw3fh87g7t" data-label="Drop blocks or content here" data-max-blocks="1" data-allowed-blocks="freeformblock; htmlblock; textblock; abtestblock; dynamicblock; enhanceddynamicblock; layoutblock; imageblock; imagecarouselblock; icemailformblock"></div>
```